# Is there a way to switch to the context of an iframe to run a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, iframe

For example, I have this simple function defined in an iframe:

```
function getLocation() { 
    return document.location.href; 
}
```

And let's say the href of my main window is a.html, and the href if my iframe is b.html on the same domain. Now, if I issue this command from the main window:

```
window.frames[0].getLocation();
```

it returns a.html. So I tried the following command, hoping it would return b.html, but it did not:

```
window.frames[0].getLocation.call(window.frames[0]);
```

The above command still returned a.html.

Is there anyway to switch context so that `window.frames[0].getLocation();` will return b.html without modifying the getLocation function?

Comment: No, not without modifying the `getLocation` function. It would need to be modified to use `this.document.location.href`. I'm assuming that the real method does something more complicated that getting the URL, because you can just do `window.frames[0].src` to get that...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes the function I want to call is part of a library that I cannot modify and that is much more complex than my simplified example above. Thanks!

Comment: If the function is declared in the iframe, it will use its URL. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @Bergi Nope. If you read correctly my question, even if the getLocation function in the "b.html" iframe is called from the "a.html" main window, value returned by getLocation() is a.html.